# Equiangular lines in $\mathbb{C}^d$.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, conjectures

Zauners' conjecture regarding equiangular lines for any $\mathbb{C}^{d}$ , holds for many dimesnions, like 17 or more(43, 31, and so on). This conjecture gives the number of equiangular lines in a given complex space $\mathbb{C}^d$. A similar result shows that for Euclidean spaces, given an angle, the number of equiangular lines can be found, result  [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.06620)  this result is for the case of a given angle, finding the number of equiangular lines like in Zauners' conjecture  (over $\mathbb{C}^{d}$), but for a given angle. Is there a number(it could be a lower/upper bound, or like Zauners' conjecture - exact), but with the constraint that it is for a given angle over $\mathbb{C}^{d}$?

Comment: Incomprehensible.

Comment: Given an angle, is there any number for equiangular lines (bounding number, upper/lower, or exact )similar to Zauners conjecture?

Comment: Not much help. I don't know what Zauner's Copnjecture is, and I don't know what you mean by "the number of equiangular lines".